# What can I do that doesn't involve arms?

Tags: gym, sports

I have a tricep injury and it's gonna be a long time until it's better.

So I'm trying to think of anything fitness related I can still do, so that I dont go crazy.

I've put together a gym routine that is mostly just legs 3x per week. I might do some running but that doesn't always agree with my knees... and I feel like it may even aggravate my triceps.

Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: When you say triceps injury, what CAN you do? Can you do row (rowing machine or weighted rows), can you do kettlebell swings? Is it only one side (so you can do single arm stuff on your healthy side, which has been shown to have benefits for the injured side as well), can you swim? Can you deadlift? etc etc.

Comment: Are you able to do movement with your biceps without it hurting your triceps? As in, can you do curls, chin-ups, pullups or even deadlifts? Or can you just not use your arms at all for a period of time?

Comment: Long distance running has basically no triceps enervation.

Comment: @DarkHippo Thanks but sadly I dont think I can do any of these. It would be okay if my left arm was injured as I could at least play tennis or something

Comment: @MJB thanks but see comment above

Comment: @JohnP I'm thinking I might give jogging a go, thanks

Comment: If it is just the one side (I'm assuming right hand side), can you do single arm work with your left side? Kettlebell clean and press? Single arm swings? Something like that? I know from breaking my right thumb (right handed), it can seem like it's completely debilitating, but I managed some decent progress working my non-dominant side for a few months.

Comment: Have you been visited by a physical therapist? Depending on your type of injury, total arm rest may not be the best solution.